# TFS PowerTools 2013 - Cross Branch Unshelve - An Item With the same key already has been added

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-power-tools, unshelve

Ok, I am pulling my hair out on this one.

I am using:

- VS 2013.2
- TFS 2013
- TFS PowerTools 2013

I shelved pending changes on the main branch, I simply want to unshelve them on a dev branch that was created after creating the shelveset without preserve pending changes.

My workspace is mapped as follows:

```
$/ = E:\TFS-01
```

I am running the below command:

```
E:\TFS-01\Src\Product\v3-DEV>tfpt unshelve "DSD-Sketch" /migrate /source:
"$/Src/Product/v3" /target:"$/Src/Product/v3-DEV"
```

And always get the following result regardless of VS running, with deleting the cache and letting VS rebuild it, etc.

> "An item with the same key has already been added."

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you run a `tf status` on the target branch and a `tf shelvesets` on the shelveset in question, maybe that may explain something.